# Не работает кнопка отправки формы

Tags: php, html

Есть такой html код:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="backgr">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <h2 class=text align="center"> Оставьте заявку </h2>
  <form name="test" method="post" action="sendform.php" align="center">
    <div>  
      <input type="text" class="brd" placeholder="Имя" name="first_name">
    </div>
    <div>  
      <input type="text" class="brd" placeholder="Телефон" name="phone_number">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="brd" placeholder="E-mail" name="client_mail">  
    </div> 
      <br>
    <div>  
      <button type="submit" form="test" name="sended" class="button">Отправить форму</button>
      </div>
        </form>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Php файл для отправки формы выглядит так:

```
<?php
    function died($error) {        
        die();
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['sended'])) {
        died("Йуху");
    }

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$phone_number = $_POST['phone_number']; 
$client_mail = $_POST['client_mail'];
$email1="leshaber24@yandex.ru";
$email_message = str_replace("#USER_NAME#", $first_name, file_get_contents("./emailinfo.html"));    
$email_message = str_replace("#PHONE_NUMBER#", $phone_number, file_get_contents("./emailinfo.html"));
$email_message = str_replace("#CLIENT_MAIL#", $client_mail, file_get_contents("./emailinfo.html"));
$headers = 'From: '.$email1."\r\n".
'Reply-To:'.$email1."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";    
mail($email1, "Тестовое задание", $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<h1 class="animated shake">Спасибо, с вами скоро свяжутся!</h1>
```

И само письмо, которое должно приходить на почту:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Письмо с сайта</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <p style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;margin:0;Margin-bottom:15px;">Привет, меня зовут: <span>#USER_NAME#</span> </p>
    <p style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;margin:0;Margin-bottom:15px;">Мой номер: <span>#PHONE_NUMBER#</span> </p>
    <p style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;margin:0;Margin-bottom:15px;">Моя почта: <span>#CLIENT_MAIL#</span> </p>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Не нажимается на сайте сама кнопка отправить и соответственно не выполняется php код.
Спасибо!

Comment: Как не нажимается? Есть пример? Где можно посмотреть

Comment: На https://abereznyak.ru весь этот пример

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка номер 1.

```
<button type="submit" form="test" name="sended" class="button">Отправить форму</button>
```

Атрибут `form="test"` уберите должно работать.
Когда HTML странно себя видёт провертывайте разметку через
https://validator.w3.org/

Ошибка номер 2.

```
$email_message = str_replace("#USER_NAME#", $first_name, file_get_contents("./emailinfo.html"));    
$email_message = str_replace("#PHONE_NUMBER#", $phone_number, file_get_contents("./emailinfo.html"));
$email_message = str_replace("#CLIENT_MAIL#", $client_mail, file_get_contents("./emailinfo.html"));
```

Нужно один раз читать `"./emailinfo.html"`

```
$html = file_get_contents("./emailinfo.html");

// Массивы с заменой
$search = array("#USER_NAME#", "#PHONE_NUMBER#", "#CLIENT_MAIL#");
$replace   = array($first_name, $phone_number, $client_mail);

$email_message = str_replace($search, $replace, $html);
```

Comment: а не видите ошибку, почему в письме, которое я получаю, подставляется только e-mail, а первые два поля нет, которые также описаны под str_replace?

Comment: @lesha_ber Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как принятый если он решил ваш вопрос (зелёная галочка слева от ответа).